# Selenium + MVC4: how to find element contained in a specific parent element

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, selenium

Im doing MVC4 application and Im creating Selenium tests for it. My problem is that I want to find element `<ul class="connectors ui-sortable"></ul>` but only contained in `<li class="empty zoneLi ui-droppable"  data-order="X">`

My solution was one added below, but it's not working:

```
private static IWebElement FindZoneByDataOrder(IWebDriver webDriver, int dataOrderId)
{
    var parentForDropElement = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[@data-order='" + dataOrderId + "']"));
    var dropElement = parentForDropElement.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@class='connectors ui-sortable']"));
    return dropElement;
}
```

part of my HTML page:

```
....
<div class="zones-system-creator" style="min-height: 430px;">
    <ul id="zonesCreateSystem" class="">
            <li data-zoneid="24829" class="empty zoneLi ui-droppable" data-order="1">                
               <div id="warningInfoBoxContainer"></div>                   
                <ul class="products ui-sortable"></ul>
                <ul class="connectors ui-sortable"></ul>
            </li>
   </ul>
</div>
....
```

UPDATE1: I changed zoneID to dataOrderId, because we care only about dataOrderId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 working solutions  if you want to find one element inside the other with Selenium:

```
result = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[@data-order='" + dataOrderId+ "']"));
var result2 = result.FindElement(By.XPath(".//ul[@class='connectors']"));


result = webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li[data-order='" + dataOrderId+ "']"));
result = result.FindElement(By.CssSelector("ul[class='connectors']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I see few issues in your code. You talked about data-order, but passed zoneId in the method. So I have added another parameter called dataOrder and searching for the `LI` element which has both zone and data order attributes:

```
"//li[@data-zoneid='" + zoneId + "'][@data-order='"+dataOrder+"'"]
```

Then searching for `ul` element of having specified class. Also combined finding the element into a single line:

**Code:**

```
private static IWebElement FindZoneByDataOrder(IWebDriver webDriver, int zoneId, int dataOrder)
{       
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-zoneid='" + zoneId + "'][@data-order='"+dataOrder+"']//ul[@class='connectors ui-sortable']"))");
}
```

**Edited Answer following question edit:**

```
return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-order='"+dataOrderId+"']//ul[starts-with(@class, 'connectors')]"));
```

Comment: I will test it tomorrow.Thanks for now

Comment: 1) you forgot about `By.XPath`  2) I made small fix in my code in order to make it more clear. 3) you code is not working

Comment: yep, forgot By.xpath. updated it now. added an edited answer.

Comment: `@id ` should be `@class`. glad you found out answer by yourself.